# Tensor Operation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have 2 tensors tensor A and tensor B as shown in the image. I want to take each 1x16 vector from tensor B and perform a dot product with the correcponding batch (axis 0 is the batch dimension in each tensor) of tensor A along axis 1 and 2 of A.  How can I do this in tensorflow. Any help with code will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I tried einsum but am confused.

The expected output shape should be (3,2,28,28).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show what exactly you have tried so far and what is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 28, 28, 16])
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 2, 16])
A_exp = A[:, tf.newaxis]
B_exp = B[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]
C = tf.reduce_sum(A_exp * B_exp, axis=-1)
print(C)
# Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(3, 2, 28, 28), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you so much...That was  what I needed.

Comment: @AbhisekDash I'm glad it helped. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: I tried to upvote but the status does not change because I have less than 15 Reputation points

Comment: @AbhisekDash That's alright, thanks. You should be able to mark it as accepted if you want (the green tick), but don't worry about it.